# How to understand what's taking up disk space?

Tags: disk-usage, software-rec

I'm looking for a linux alternative to [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). I would like to know what is taking up space on my hard drives.

A program that works on console and doesn't require a UI is preferred .

Comment: `ncdu` is my preferred answer, but I see the first answer says you're having problems with it that aren't in your question.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Based on your issues in [installing ncdu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/how-to-install-linux-programs) my recommendation would be to use `du` and `sort` on together.

For instance:

- `du /home | sort -rn` (will search all files/directories under /home and sort them by largest to smallest.
- `du -h /home | sort -rh` (same but will show it in MB/KB/etc) - Note this requires coreutils 7.5 or newer (`sort --version` to check)

You can replace /home with any directory of your choice.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks for the help. My coreutils is 5.97 - is this why the sort order of du -h isn't right?

Comment: Yep, you'd have to settle for `du /home | sort -rn` with coreutils 5.97 or use some 'magic' with perl etc as demonstrated over on ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/q/62411/60012)

Comment: OTOH if there is a big sub-sub-directory its bloat will show multiple time (for that dir and each parent dir) at the top of the results, and IMHO that distracts from the true bloat. Using "ncdu" suggested below could help with that, I'm gonna try it. =)

Comment: I find the -size option to "find" useful as well, as it lets you find all files under a certain.  At least for GNU find, you can do something like:  "find . -size +100M" to find files larger than 100M below the current directory.

Answer (score 131):

If you want a command-line tool, I prefer [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu), an ncurses version of `du`. It scans the disk (or a given folder) and then shows the top-level space usages; you can select a given directory to get the corresponding summary for that directory, and go back without needing to reanalyze:

[image: Screenshot of ncdu]

---

If you're ok with a GUI program, [Filelight](http://methylblue.com/filelight/) is the closest thing to WinDirStat I've found; it shows a graphical view of space consumption:

[image: Screenshot of Filelight]

Like `ncdu`, Filelight lets you select a given directory to get the breakdown for that directory

Comment: don't you think [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat) is closer to WinDirStat?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, this was answered in 2010. 5 years before the initial commit of QDirStat https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/commit/78d9fef5c15c246f72c3ad3d1a2b2c8223ccefce

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky And QDirStat is the descendant of KDirStat, which WinDirStat [is actually a port](https://windirstat.net/background.html) of. So their comment is actually (even if indirectly) absolutely relevant.

Comment: @adamency, cool history! So QDirStat and WinDirStat are cousins. I didn't mean the comment left by Janus was irrelevant, QDirStat is a good recommendation. Just that the author of the answer could not have known that since it was released way after they answered!

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky Yup I understood that, no worries :)

Answer (score 59):

[You should be aware that WinDirStat is actually a port of KDirStat](https://windirstat.net/background.html), which is a Linux/KDE program. So, if you are looking for a Linux alternative to WinDirStat, you certainly should take a look at [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/). It is already packaged in most distros, just install it.

Another alternative is FileLight, already cited by Michael Mrozek, and the Konqueror plugin `fsview` (you can run it standalone from the command-line).

Comment: Wow, I never realized that (I guess "Win" in the name should've been a giveaway). A coworker once asked me if there was a Linux version of [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php); I died inside a little

Comment: @previous comment.  ouch.  Just ouch.

Comment: Note that it will be called K4DirStat for Ubuntu if installing via software center

Comment: or `sudo apt-get install k4dirstat`

Answer (score 39):

Another GUI program is: [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/)

[image]

Comment: In deed, if I'm on Ubuntu I won't bother to look for any alternative. `baobap` is just enough.

Comment: It also shows number of files, which sometimes needs to be checked as well as disk space

Comment: Now part of GNOME out of the box, on Fedora at least.

Comment: However, when I used it on an NTFS volume (a former Windows boot volume, specifically) of around 100 GB, it kept counting and reached nearly 500 GB in the total size and still kept going - I guess it doesn't have any smarts about counting hardlinks and symlinks.

Comment: Ubuntu - no installation necessary!

Answer (score 16):

Use [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat) (formerly KDirStat).

It includes a perl script that generates a cache file on the server/console without any need for an UI to be running/installed; transfer it to your desktop machine and view it in the gui client.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256516/186308 for details.

Comment: it is ridiculously fast. very nice tool

Answer (score 7):

I prefer the following command line:

```
$  du -s -m -x * | sort -n
```

Breaking it down, `du` shows disk usage; `-s` says print the total for each argument (each item in the current directory), `-m` says show the size in Megabytes.  This makes it easier for sort to work; sort doesn't really understand the `-h` output.  The `-x` ignores other filesystems; this is useful when trying to find space hogs in `/var`, and `/var/spool/foo` is a different filesystem.

Comment: Doesn't the top answer already use `du`?

Comment: Yes, but du /home on my systems returns tens of thousands of files; I rarely care what the (say) 100 largest of those files are; I typically want to know which subdirectories are taking up the most space.

Comment: Instead of -s, I specified --max-depth=2, as I wanted to go one directory down from the root directory, but your answer pointed me in that direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There's also this cool python script from /www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

`bzr branch lp:~mcfletch/squaremap/trunk squaremap`

It's not the most feature rich, but it's run from a single python script so it's extremely portable.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you looked at the about screen on windirstat it showed you that it's based on kdirstat.

http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I like the answer - but could you add some context or details?

Answer (score 5):

You could also try [GD Map](http://gdmap.sourceforge.net/), another GUI tool based on treemaps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[xdiskusage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/) is very flexible, lightweight with very lean dependencies, easy to compile..

It shows a tree left-to-right that you can navigate with mouse or arrow keys, zoom in (click or enter), hide some parts for a better view, change sort order, number of colors etc with keys or context menu.

It's so lighweight that you can use it on a remote SSH link with good performance.  In this case I recommend `-q` command line option to disable the progress bar that appears while files are walked.

You can also optionally run `du` yourself beforehand.

One situation is a remote filesystem which is full or near-full. On that system run `du -ak | gzip >log_of_disk_usage.txt.gz`, fetch the output and run `gzip -dc log_of_disk_usage.txt.gz | xdiskusage -aq` locally.
Or even `ssh myremotesystem "cd /filesystem_near_full/ ; du -ak | gzip" > log_of_disk_usage.txt.gz` to store the result locally without writing anything remotely.

`xdiskusage` does not offer to modify the filesystem (like move to trash, etc) but you can copy a path to clipboard and paste that into a file manager, terminal etc.

[image: xdiskusage screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I have recently used command line tool (CLI, not TUI): http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/

It produces a PNG file which you can view somewhere else. It also has a CGI script.

Most likely you are not limited to text mode at your local workstation, so it should be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Also to see the files in a specific directory sorted by size after you have found the directory using du use:

```
ls -lrSh
```

Answer (score 1):

Duc (https://duc.zevv.nl/) will work from the command line.

It can be installed and used like this in Debian 9:

```
# apt install duc
# duc index /
# duc graph /
```

With this you'll get a file named `duc.png` in the current directory. Now, you can copy this file to another GUI capable computer and it will look like this:
[image: duc.png]

NOTE: Duc is the replacement for the tool that @OCTAGRAM mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

For btrfs filesystems, you may like my tool, [btdu](https://github.com/CyberShadow/btdu):

[image]

- Starts showing results instantly
- Shows snapshots / reflinks / cloned files correctly
- Shows real (compressed) usage of compressed files