# How to install software on Red Hat?

Tags: command-line, rhel, package-management, software-installation

What's the simplest way to download/install software on Red Hat Linux (from bash command line)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux and derivatives:

```
$ yum install foo
```

For Fedora:

```
$ dnf install foo
```

For Debian and derivatives such as Ubuntu (run this as [root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063)) :

```
# apt-get install foo
```

Comment: I'm trying "yum install ncdu", and getting "No package ncdu available." (See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space/3970#3970). What now?

Comment: @ripper234 Not all distros provide ncdu

Comment: So, what are my options then? Do I have to download the source and compile?

Comment: Suse uses yast not yum

Comment: @ripper234 ... I don't know what that is but I'll bet it's in an external repo, try asking a second question on here "how can I install ncdu on Red Hat" and ask if it's available in any repo's in the text.

Comment: @xeno - done. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/how-can-i-install-ncdu-on-red-hat

Comment: @xeno: fixed it. :)

Comment: @xenoterracide: actually, SUSE uses `zypper` - I think it did back in 2010 too.

Comment: @David libzypp became a new backend for yast, and it can be used directly as zypper but afaik yast is still the main interface even if reality says it's working via zypper which uses rpms.

Comment: @xenoterracide: True - but then the same can be said of APT (aptitude) or YUM.

Answer (score 2):

For Debian/Ubuntu

```
aptitude install firefox
```

For Fedora i think it is

```
yum install firefox
```

[**note**] Run these as [root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063).

Comment: @Stefan, what's up with # and $ ?

Comment: see this [discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192/). `#` means the command is run as root, `$` is normal user.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux, it happens that the package you are looking for is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), so you can install that:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

and then you can `yum install ncdu`.

If you are using ancient Red Hat Linux, the answer is *for the love of all that is holy*, time to upgrade to Fedora.

Comment: Upgrading is not always possible. Have some compassion :)

Comment: @spemble Well, sure, but even at the time I wrote that, Red Hat Linux 9 (the last release) had been out of support for almost _seven years_. Now, it's been _fourteen_. The number of unpatched local and remote exploits is horrifying to consider.

Comment: My job has me working on RHEL 4.6 and SCO Unix v5. You can imagine the frustration. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

In debian based system you can use 
`sudo apt-get install foo` 
to download you can use [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL distrib for remote installation and repositories installation to yum OK, Here we have some additional details :

RHEL2, RHEL3 and RHEL4 :

```
    up2date -i pkg-name
```

RHEL5, RHEL6, RHEL7, RHEL8  :

```
    yum install pkg-name
```

Note RHEL8 can also :
dnf install pkg-name

think about module appstream for apps in RHEL8 :
for instance : mariadb

```
      #use the default module version
      yum module install mariadb 
      
      #select module version
      yum module install mariadb:10.5

      #select the profile
      yum module install mariadb:10.5/Client
```

RHEL7/RHEL8 :
yum group install group-pkg-name

RHEL5, RHEL6,RHEL7 and RHEL8 :

```
    yum groupinstall group-pkg-name
```

RHEL2,RHEL3,RHEL4 :
up2date "@group-pkg-name"

If you have to install any rpm package local, avoid to use :

```
    rpm -ivh http://...
```

and prefer use :

```
    OBSOLETE : yum localinstall http://... 
    now : yum install http://mywebiste/mypackage.rpm
```

or

Legacy distribution RHEL2, RHEL3, RHEL4 :

```
    up2date -k pkg-name
```

Note : maybe http://... if not wget -0 http://... after up2date -k pkg-name

All of this to keep your metainformation yum (or up2date) ok and sync with rpm.