# How can I install ncdu on Red Hat?

Tags: command-line, install, rhel

The answers provided [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/how-to-install-linux-programs-in-red-hat) doesn't help.

I'ved tried

```
yum install ncdu
```

But I'm getting

```
No package ncdu available
```

Comment: Curious; from what I can tell, it's in the [repositories][1].


  [1]: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/ncdu

Answer (score 29):

You will need to download the latest `ncdu` package from http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu with `wget`.

Navigate to a directory with write access, such as your home directory.

```
wget https://dev.yorhel.nl/download/ncdu-1.13.tar.gz
```

then extract the tarball, with:

```
tar -xzvf ncdu-1.13.tar.gz
```

this will create a new folder named `ncdu-1.13`. Enter that folder and execute:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

If it can't find ncurses.h and the configure fails,

```
checking for ncurses.h... no
configure: error: required header file not found
```

you'll [have to install `curses` library headers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-error-cursesh-no-such-file-directory/)

```
sudo dnf install ncurses ncurses-devel
```

After installing the library, execute the configure step again.

Then run,

```
make
```

and

```
sudo make install
```

and you are done.

You can optionally remove the `ncdu-1.13.tar.gz` file and the directory where the source files were extracted as you don't need them anymore.

Comment: // , Doesn't this require other dependencies?

Comment: // , Also, I get the following error when I attempt `./configure`: `[nbasanese@rhel022 ncdu-1.11]$ ./configure –-prefix='/usr'`
`configure: error: invalid variable name: '–-prefix'`

Comment: @Nathan Just use one dash before `prefix`. Didn't run into any other dependencies aside from curses.

Comment: `sudo apt install libncurses5-dev` on debian/ubuntu (using APT)

Comment: On Oracle Linux (version 7, anyway), the `dnf` package manager does not exist, so use `sudo yum install ncurses ncurses-devel` for that step.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux, I do not think ncdu is in the RHEL server repositories.  I do not have a machine where I can check if it is in the workstation repositories, but I suspect it isn't.  If it isn't, one option is the use EPEL ([faq](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#What_is_EPEL.3F)):

> EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise
>   Linux) is a volunteer-based community
>   effort from the Fedora project to
>   create a repository of high-quality
>   add-on packages that complement the
>   Fedora-based Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   (RHEL) and its compatible spinoffs,
>   such as CentOS and Scientific Linux.

`ncdu` does seem to be in the EPEL repositories intended to work with RHEL 4 and RHEL 5.  Directions for how to use these repositories can be found here:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

Alternatively, you can always download the tool from the upstream website:

http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

and follow the directions in the INSTALL file.  However, this will require you to chase down dependencies and install the tools needed to build the project.

Answer (score 12):

First visit the below link and install the epel according to the OS type.

[How to Install and Enable EPEL Repository on CentOS 8/7/6](https://www.tecmint.com/install-epel-repository-on-centos/)

Once the EPEL repo is installed, ncdu can be installed with following command:

```
yum install ncdu
```

**Note:** The above command will work if you have RHEL Subscription / Preconfigured with yum install.

To use ncdu, enter the following command:

```
ncdu
```

Answer (score 12):

install epel repository

```
yum install epel-release
```

install ncdu

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install ncdu
```

Comment: Error: Unknown repo: 'epel'

Comment: Most straight forward solution in a Rocky Linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

On Amazon Linux 2:

```
# amazon-linux-extras install epel
# yum install ncdu
```