# Install NCDU on Scientific from EPEL

Tags: yum, rpm, repository, scientific-linux

**Introduction**

The commands specified in the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/how-can-i-install-ncdu-on-red-hat/3986#3986) and [this documentation](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/) have been applied to install NCDU on Scientific using EPEL without success.

According to [this documentation](http://www.tecmint.com/ncdu-a-ncurses-based-disk-usage-analyzer-and-tracker/) it should be possible to install ncdu using EPEL.

*setup EPEL repo*

```
$ sudo wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
warning: epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 060
8b895: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed
```

*install ncdu*

```
$ sudo yum install ncdu -y
Loaded plugins: security
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

**Question:** How to install NCDU on Scientific from EPEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks correct in terms of setting up the EPEL repository and attempting to intsall NCDU. I even confirmed that hte NCDU RPM is in fact in [that repository](http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/6/x86_64/):

- http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ncdu-1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

So this particular issue looks like it has little to do with the RPM, and more to do with the setup of the EPEL repository on your system.

#### The quick answer

If you just want to install NCDU you can simply do this to manually install the RPM from that repository:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall \
    http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ncdu-1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

#### The long answer

If you'd like to figure out what's wrong with your YUM setup I'd first start with running the command `yum clean all`.

After that I'd double check that the `.repo` files for the EPEL repo are in fact setup correctly undre `/etc/yum.repo.d/`.

I'd also remove and re-install the EPEL RPM file:

```
$ sudo yum remove epel-release
$ sudo yum localinstall epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Executing `ncdu` after installing `http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ncdu-1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` results in `ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help`. Thank you. Now it works. I will accept the answer. I also would like to upvote, but a reputation of at least 15 is required.