# Command line linux alternative for Windirstat/SpaceMonger?

Tags: linux, rhel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to understand what's taking up space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space)

What's a good command line utility/script to analyze a folder structure and find out what's taking up all the space? The granularity of `df` is way to large.

Specifically I'd like something that can run with limited permissions (e.g. on shared hosting)
I seem to be running on Redhat, if that matters.

Comment: Er...[didn't you ask this a year ago?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - I vaguely remembered something like that. Now next time I'll be able to find one of these questions. Sorry for not looking too hard, I was in the "fire question away" mood.

Comment: ncdu ncdu ncdu ncdu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a treemap (which I agree can be nice), but `du` will give you a breakdown by directory. Look into the `-d` option, to only show a certain level of depth.

Also note that you can sort the output, but you should use `-k` or similar, otherwise '1M' will sort before '2K' - probably not what you want.

Example: show size summary for all directories in current directory:

```
du -d 1 .
```

Comment: If you haven't seen ncdu you should check it out as it is even better for large scans where you wish to be able to drill down: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3964/13779

Comment: Use `sort -h` for "human-numeric sort", then it will get M, G etc right. `du -h | sort -h`