# Tools to visualize file size distributions

Tags: files, gui, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to understand what's taking up space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space)

Are there any tools in Linux for graphically visualizing the distribution of file sizes under a given path?

I am looking for something along the lines of [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), but on Linux, e.g. see snapshot below:

[image]

Also, are there any similar tools that would show such distribution **on a terminal**? (I usually use `df -csh *`, but this only shows one level of a file hierarchy, and does not have any mechanisms for navigating a report, e.g. as I browse up and down through a file hierarchy).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am using [Disk Usage Analyser](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2010/01/baobab-linux-graphical-disk-usage.html) (aka [Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/index.html)), its output looks like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_VN8zHqq8Ns8/S0nrlyb7p-I/AAAAAAAADSk/qxD7qvcw3TA/s1600-h/baobab.png). (It's a `png`, couldn't paste it here). I believe it's part of the regular Ubuntu installation.

Also, there's [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/), of which WinDirStat is a clone. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Check out this page [6 Great Apps to View Disk Usage in Linux](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/) for a collection of other tools.

Comment: this was rebuilt and is now called `QDirStat`. It is IMMENSELY fast, seems like some dark magic to me. I definitely recommend it

Comment: @Blauhirn Thanks, I'll definitely will check it out.

Answer (score 16):

Another ncurses alternative is [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).

Comment: That works really well.  And even on a character ssh terminal.

Comment: ...and is very fast

Comment: Great tool! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I am using `ncdu` for that purpose on the command line. The Homepage of that tool includes a list of similar software:  http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

On KDE there is [Filelight](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/filelight?content=99561), which does a similar job, but with a slightly different representation.

[image]

Comment: `ncdu` is great!

Comment: Ditto!  Love `ncdu` - Thanks from September 2017 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Answer (score 5):

An oldy but goody: [xdu](https://web.archive.org/web/20131111062856/http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/xdu/)  It's an X11 display program, but you actually run it from the command line: `du | xdu`  I believe that `du` also takes an argument, the directory in which to start.  Apparently you can also use `xdu` to display other hierarchically-arranged numerical data, too.

`xdu` is available as a package on Debian. And appart from the link to the web archive given above, you can also get [an updated version of the code from Debian](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/xdu.git) to compile it on your system.

It isn't hard.  You'll need `xmkmf` or something from the "imake" package of products.

You could also try [xdiskuage](http://xdiskusage.sourceforge.net/) said to be inspired by `xdu` which is more recent and more actively maintained.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The GTK Tool Baobab looks just like the tool you are showing above.

The NCURSES tool [TDU](http://webonastick.com/tdu/) will provide you with a nice text-mode console tool.

[image: Baobab Screen Shot]
[image: TDU Screen Shot]