# Can I use KdirStat over SSH?

Tags: ssh, centos, disk-usage

I have a headless server running Centos 5.9. I can only SSH into it, is it possible to use KdirStat or a similar tool to get a graphical view of disk usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) to mount `/` on your desktop to `/mnt/server/` on your pc. Then you start Kdirstat on this directory.

Comment: Why downnvoted?

Comment: Seriously, two downvotes without a mention as to why?

Comment: In fact it's exactly what he needs to do without x fordwarding? Lol.

Comment: That's why it's rather sad...

Comment: I am Gilles and I approve of this answer.

Comment: Yeah Elias came in here earlier today and DV'ed all of our A's and then posted his, assuming that they were all incorrect. All of the A's are appropriate, try not to let 1 bad seed bother you 8-)

Comment: Downvoted because it is extremely slow.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `qdirstat-cache-writer` or `kdirstat-cache-writer` Perl script on your server, copy the file to your desktop machine and view it there with QDirStat / KDirStat.

See also:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat 
https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/tree/master/scripts

Update 2017-02-23: **Detailed instructions** available at

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md

-- HuHa (QDirStat / KDirStat author)

Comment: This! :)
Please also note that for cache import of "/"-directory to work properly you need to use the latest dev version (build yourself) - currently available ppa of last release for ubuntu contains a bug. Building works like a charm though. Perfect solution though!

Answer (score 2):

If you're running an X server on the system you're running `ssh` on you should need to do nothing more than this:

```
$ ssh -X remoteserver KdirStat
```

Here for example I'm `ssh`'ing into a CentOS 5.9 system running [Babaob](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/), another disk utilization app that comes with GNOME.

[image: babaob]

Incidentally there are a lot of applications for analyzing disk usage. I wrote them up here on my blog in a post titled: [Command Line Tools for Analyzing Disk Usage on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5845/command-line-tools-for-analyzing-disk-usage-on-fedoracentosrhel/#more-5845).

Answer (score 1):

You can log into the server and use `du`, redirecting that output to a file (`-a` = include files, not just directories; `-x` = one filesystem only):

```
$ du -ax / > ~/root-du
```

then you can scp that file back, and browse it graphically with `xdiskusage`

```
$ scp server:root-du ~/root-du
$ xdiskusage ~/root-du
```

Of course, you can run `du` remotely over ssh, and pipe it to `xdiskusage` as well:

```
$ ssh server 'du -ax /' | xdiskusage
```

but I prefer to use files, so I can re-open it, compare before & after, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have all the X environment (libraries, programs etc), but ssh can do X forwarding Trusted with `-Y` untrusted `-X` options.

try

```
xhost +
ssh -X user@remote_server
xclock
exit
xhost -
```

Answer (score 0):

Having X installed/running on a server is considered to be a really bad practice, mostly because of security and stability issues.

Simply use KDE's KIOs which make it really easy to use a lot of different protocols in KDE applications.

Use a URL like `sftp://user@host/some/directory` to access the remote filesystem via SSH/SFTP:

[image: KDE Filelight]

Comment: X isn't installed in any o the solutions you just downvoted!!