# How can I remove error writing to /tmp/cc6sZ4kE.s: No space left on device?

Tags: files, disk-usage

I have this error when I compile a C program:

> writing to /tmp/cc6sZ4kE.s: No space left on device

How do I fix this?

Comment: Add more space to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 6):

“No space left on device” means that the disk is full. You need to make some space on the disk (partition) that contains `/tmp`, or more precisely on the filesystem that contains `/tmp`.

This has nothing to do with the content of the program (unless you managed to write a program that compiles to a multi-gigabyte binary).

Check where `/tmp` is located and how much space there is:

```
df /tmp
```

If `/tmp` is its own filesystem (it says `/tmp` in the “Mounted on” column) then check where the space is being used:

```
du /tmp | sort -n
```

Look at the directories at the end of the list. To see the biggest files in a directory, run e.g.

```
ls -lrS /tmp
```

If `/tmp` is on the root filesystem (it says `/` in the “Mounted on” column in the output of `df /tmp`) then you need to make some space on your disk. See [How to understand what's taking up disk space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-disk-space)