# Graphical disk space manager for linux terminal

Tags: disk-usage, size

I want to export the results of a recursive `ls` command.
Then open it in a disk space manager software like Treesize.

Do you know of a program that is able to to that?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-disk-space and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux

Comment: But I actually want GUI, I want to export the dirlist and open it in program with gui